# How to access messages.properties with thymeleaf from javascript, but using variables defined in javascript

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to access the values ​​of the messages.properties but concatenate some value obtained from javascript to it. I am trying to do something like this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
     var identificationTypeId = 1;
     var identificationTypeValue = [[#{identificationType.identificationTypeId}]];
</script>
```

I have in mesagges.properties this:enter code here

```
identificationType.1=Passport
```

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Thymeleaf doesn't have access to client side JavaScript variables.

Alternatives might include:

1. Putting all the messages you need available into your JavaScript and accessing it with JavaScript.  Something like this for example:

   ```
   var messages = [];
   messages[0] = /*[[#{identificationType.0}]]*/ '';
   messages[1] = /*[[#{identificationType.1}]]*/ '';
   messages[2] = /*[[#{identificationType.2}]]*/ '';

   var identificationTypeId = 1;
   var identificationTypeValue = messages[identificationTypeId];
   ```
2. Using an ajax call to retrieve the message.