# Thymeleaf, how to use inline javascript dynamic variable to call message.properties

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
 let data = data[i]; // i is dynamic string value for message properties
 let message = [[#{'message.data.'+ data}]]; // tring to concate the string but not working
```

Output message:

> ??message.data.message_de_DE??

How can I use `data` variable in the `message` inline javascript?

Comment: You can't... Thymeleaf is interpreted before JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for the help. One thing if both `data` and `message` variables are in Ajax call and Ajax call happens on button click after Thymeleaf interpreted. In that case, it might be the case, can I?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... there are definitely ways to accomplish this, but not through using JavaScript variables... you could put all the messages on your page for example like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72015988/how-to-access-messages-properties-with-thymeleaf-from-javascript-but-using-vari/72017162#72017162 or you create an ajax method that returns a message based on a string.